# Reload a page from a different page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, reload

I have a button on one page (page1), which opens a form in another tab (page2).  On submit of the form, page2 closes and sends data back to page1. I need page1 to reload after the data has been sent over, but I can only do this from page2.  I do not have access to page1 code.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: How do you send data back to page 1?

Comment: through a YUI io-xdr flash transport, to circumvent cross-domain issues

Comment: assuming JS is used to launch it page2 can call `opener.location.reload()`

Comment: What is a `YUI io-xdr flash transport,`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever mechanism you are using to send back to page 1, you can also use it to execute this line of code:

```
 location.reload();
```

which will cause page 1 to reload.